# Text processing to find co-occurences of strings

Tags: python, c++, regex, machine-learning, nlp

I need to process a series of space separated strings i.e. text sentences. ‘Co-occurrence’ is when two tags (or words) appear on the same sentence. I need to list all the co-occurring words when they appear together on at least two lines (two sentences). The list has to be ordered and spaced.

Example of input:

tag1 tag2

tag1 tag3

tag2 tag4 tag3

tag2 tag3

The output should be:

tag2 tag3

I can’t assume that the input will fit in memory.
What I know is there are not going to be more that 10,000 tags.
My problem is the brute force of reading the whole input and creating a matrix of all the words and ticking it out when a co-occurrence appears will not work.

There must be an algorithm or methodology that I've not found.
I'd appreciate tips/links or references to an algo or function that might be of use. I understand c, c++, MATLAB, python

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat cumbersome:

```
import re
tags = list(set(input_string.split()))
tag_length = len(tags)
for i in xrange(tag_length - 1):
  for j in xrange(tag_length - 2 - i):
    tag1, tag2 = tags[i], tags[i + j + 1]
    matches = re.findall(r'\b{0}\b.+\b{1}\b'.format(tag1, tag2), input_string)
    if len(matches) > 1:
       print tag1, tag2
```

Answer (score 1):

why tag1 isn't output? there is in first and second line..?

```
all_tags_generator = (set(line.rstrip().split()) for line in sys.stdin)  # or change sys.stdin to open("your file")

all_tags = set()
for new_tags in all_tags_generator:
    realy_new_tags = new_tags.difference(all_tags)
    for tag in realy_new_tags:
        print(tag, end=" ")
    all_tags.update(intersection)
```

Comment: tag1 is not output as it does not appear twice with another tag - this is the 'co-occurrence' rule, i.e. tag1 appears on line one and two but with two different tags (tag2 and tag3) so it cant be on the output.