# Combinations of words that co-occur most often across strings

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

**Here's the problem...**

I have a list of strings:

```
strings = ['one two three four', 'one two four five', 'four one two', 'three four']
```

I'm trying to find combinations of words that co-occur in two or more strings.

**And here's the output I'm trying to get...**

- [one, two, four] - 3 times
- [three, four] - 2 times
- [one, two] - 3 times
- [two, four] - 3 times

The combinations could be any length of two or more words.

**Here's what I've already looked at** - though I'm not having much luck finding anything I can bootstrap for my needs : (

- [Text processing to find co-occurences of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763898/text-processing-to-find-co-occurences-of-strings)
- [Efficient way of extracting co-occurence values of specific word pairs from Python Counter() results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65824631/efficient-way-of-extracting-co-occurence-values-of-specific-word-pairs-from-pyth)

Comment: For the record, I think that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65825140/891919) is the most appropriate and the most efficient. The calculation of the powerset is likely to cause serious efficiency issues if a real text is used as input, because the vocabulary will be very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the powersets with minimum 2 combinations and count the combinations:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
from collections import Counter

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html
def powerset(iterable, MIN=2):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(MIN, len(s)+1))

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(set(powerset(s.split()))
            for s in strings))

# keep counts of 2 or more
out = {k: v for k, v in c.items() if v >= 2}
```

Output:

```
{('three', 'four'): 2, 
 ('two', 'four'): 2, 
 ('one', 'two', 'four'): 2, 
 ('one', 'four'): 2, 
 ('one', 'two'): 3}
```

##### keep order

Use:

```
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(tuple(powerset(s.split()))
            for s in strings))
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this include cases like 'four one two' where the items are in a different order (without having to type all possible orders into the powerset section)? It looks like right now it leaves those out, and I'm hoping to be able to do this for strings in all different orders with combinations up to 10 words...

Comment: If you use `tuple` instead of `set` this will consider order